# build error when adding crashlytics dependency in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, crashlytics

I want to add Crashlytics in my project

I add below dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.0'
```

my project dependencies

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'
implementation 'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'
implementation 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9.8'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev135-1.23.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: 
'4.3.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.pusher:chatkit-android:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
implementation 
'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'

// Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.0'
```

I got below error

```
class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng, unresolved 
supertypes:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm
e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved.
Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
```

Dependency after grouping all firebase Dependencies under BoM

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'
    implementation 'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'
    implementation 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9.8'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev135-1.23.0'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.pusher:chatkit-android:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    // implementation files('libs/itextpdf-5.3.3.jar')
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
    implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'

    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'


    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'

    //FireBase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'

}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to also show all of the dependencies in your build.gradle after you added crashlytics.

Comment: Edit the question to what?

Answer (score 0):

When using Firebase dependencies, the versions must all come from the same "release" point in time.  What you have no shows a **lot** of old Firebase dependencies from many years ago.  When you added Crashlytics, it took them all out of sync.

What you will need to do is upgrade all of your Firebase dependencies to match what you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).  Even better, since you have so many Firebase dependencies, use the [Firebase BoM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom) to choose a single release version for all of them without having to specify individual dependency versions.

Comment: I have tried to upgrade gms-play-services then I got this error message it's self explanatory but how can I know which latest version that matches between gms and firebase?
 
All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 17.0.0, 11.8.0. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0

Comment: The documentation I linked to has all the information you need.  The version numbers no longer have to be the same.  The requirement was eliminated many years ago.  Each dependency's version just has to come from the same release, which corresponds to a single BoM version.  That's why it's better to use the BoM now - it automatically keeps each dependency version in sync with each other.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I have grouped all firebase dependencies under BoM 26.1.1 but still the same error posted in the question is present.

Comment: I can't see what you've done, so I don't know if you've done it correctly.  It sounds like it's not correct.

Comment: You'll need to update the play services dependencies as well.

Comment: I did update play services and I got bunch of new errors